# Configuration to accept all server certificates in Java 17 or Apache camel

Tags: apache-camel, java-17

I am running an https client application developed using Apache camel and runs on Java 17.
Is there any configuration ( not code change ) available in Java 17 or Apache camel to accept all server certificates ( both trusted and untrusted ) ?

Answer (score 0):

no, you have to import de certifcate for https request, in http is not necesary.
this certificate has to be import in the cacert of your jdk this is the line you need to import it.

```
keytool -import -alias example -keystore "yourjdkdirection\cacerts" -file yourcertificate.cer
```